# Java - BufferedImage - clear the screen after each iteration

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm drawing onto a transparent background, but in each loop, I'd like the screen to be cleared, instead of drawing on the screen from before.

Is there a way to wipe the drawing screen in Java?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on exactly what your problem is. If you don't get a decent answer soon, can you elaborate a bit more on your problem and show some pertinent code?

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for [`Graphics#clearRect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). You'll probably need to set the surface background to a transparent color, though:

```
graphics.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
```

Comment: I am proposing a possible solution, so why should it be a comment?

Comment: @ina - It does if the background color is set correctly. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work with clear() in http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html - somehow  StdDraw.clear(new Color(0,0,0,0)); after each iteration does not wipe the background since it is transparent

Comment: @ina - I am not sure about `StdDraw`. Is `Graphics` causing problems?